# how to calculate covariance

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I am looking for the error covariance of two sensors (gyro & accelerometer). Since I do have the data sheets I was wondering if you could tell me how to obtain the value. I do know that the covariance might change but is there a way to estimate it from noise specifications or something similar?

In both cases I have the power spectral density of the noise. Is this the value I need? The information I am referring to is on page 12 and page 13 in this [document](http://www.invensense.com/mems/gyro/documents/PS-MPU-6000A.pdf).

Thanks for any suggestions :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58921/how-to-calculate-covariance/) by [georgwi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4460/georgwi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 281 on 2013-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your link does not work. In general, if you have the data, you could just use the sample covariance as an estimate (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_sample_covariance#Sample_covariance).

---

Originally posted by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) with karma: 529 on 2013-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0